# How to set a global environment variable in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an organization in my azure devops account. And several project in this organization. Each project has its own build pipeline.

So I need some environment variables to use in every project. I see each project build pipeline has own variables. Can I set a variable in organization level for common usage?

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature still in NEW state: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/library-of-variable-and-task-groups-shared-between/365752

As workaround, consider using external resources like Azure Key Vault to store common settings. Then you may use [AzureKeyVault@2 - Azure Key Vault v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-key-vault-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to download secrets.